# How to store subprocess call output to a file python

Tags: python, subprocess

i have a script in bash that i am running in python using call from subprocess. 
i want the script output (strings) to be stored in a file. i tried working on a code that is

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='',
                    datefmt='',
                    filename='E:\FYP\FYPPP\AMAPT\log.txt',
                    filemode='w')=
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
logging.info(call("sh amapt.sh", shell=True))
logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')
logger1.debug('test.')
logger1.info('test1.')
logger2.warning('test2.')
logger2.error('test3.')
```

But displays the output as an integer of my script. check the image here 
[I want the yellow/green output text to be stored in file but it is storing 255 instead of this text from my script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szzng.png)

Guide me please.

Answer (score 0):

`call` returns the return code of your script. You need to get the *output* of the process:

```
logging.info(check_output("sh amapt.sh"))
```

notes:

- if process fails you'll get an exception
- you don't need `shell=True`

To get the output no matter what you could use `Popen` instead for instance like this:

```
logging.info(Popen("sh amapt.sh",stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT).stdout.read())
```

The added `,stderr=STDOUT` allows to get standard error in the log as well.

or from python 3.5 you can use [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `Popen`

```
logging.info(run("sh amapt.sh",stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT).stdout.read())
```

Comment: logging.info(subprocess.Popen("sh amapt.sh",stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
it worked.

Comment: "sh amapt.sh -s abc.apk" i have to use this command. its not working with Popen? what do i do? simple script is running but with this command its not

Comment: maybe restore `shell=True`, but I think redirecting stderr to the log would be better, at least you'd see the error. Let me edit.

Comment: where do i add shell=true?

Comment: `logging.info(subprocess.Popen("sh amapt.sh -s try.apk",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell= True).stdout.read())` this code doesnt works it doesnt even runs the script